# Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/users/me meanstack jasmine testing

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

Please help my http request keeps failing and i have tried different methods from Internet

**test.js**

```
{
describe('EcdreportController', function(){

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('mean');
        module('mean.ecdreport');
    });

    // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
    var EcdreportController,
        $scope,
        $httpBackend,
        $stateParams,
        $location;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _$location_, _$stateParams_, _$httpBackend_,$http) {

        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

        EcdreportController = $controller('EcdreportController', {
            $scope: $scope,
            $http : $http
        });

        $stateParams = _$stateParams_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $location = _$location_;

    }));

    afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });
    it('$scope.getdatamodel',function($http){

        // test expected GET request
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/v1/getdatamodel').respond(200);
        //expect($httpBackend.flush).not.toThrow();
        $httpBackend.flush();
        $scope.getDataModel()

        expect($scope.datamodel).toEqual(data)



    });


})
}
```

**controllers.js**

```
$scope.getDataModel = function() {

    $http({url:'/api/v1/getdatamodel', method:"GET"})
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log('Datamodel successful');
            $scope.datamodel = data[0];
            console.log('datamodel', data);

        })
        .error(function(error) {
            $scope.datamodel =[];
        });
}
//   console.log("Trying to get datamodel");
$scope.getDataModel();`
```

**terminal results**

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) EcdreportController $scope.getdatamodel FAILED
Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/users/me
Expected GET /api/v1/getdatamodel in bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js (line 1412)
$httpBackend@bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1412:90
n@bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:98:461
bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:95:490
bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:130:511
$eval@bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:145:107
$digest@bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:142:178
flush@bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1791:45
packages/custom/ecdreport/public/tests/ecdreport.tests.js:71:21
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest in bower_components/angular/angular.min.js (line 137)
n@bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:137:402
$digest@bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:142:31
verifyNoOutstandingExpectation@bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1823:45
packages/custom/ecdreport/public/tests/ecdreport.tests.js:63:46
```

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 3 (1 FAILED) (0.056 secs / 0.074 secs)